# How to handle PSEUDO_LANGUAGE in translations with Xcode

Tags: xcode, localization, xliff

I have localized my Xcode project with 2 languages:

English - (developer language)
German

I have translated every Text in the User interface formatted like:

BUTTON_UPLOAD
ALERT_MESSAGE_WRONG_PASSWORD

I call these TOKENS.

My aim:
I want to export these TOKENS in XLIFF for English translation like

"BUTTON_Upload" = "Upload" (I know that this is not the XLIFF Format, It's just for demonstrating)

But the problem what I have is now, is that I only can translate

English -> German

But actually it is

TOKEN Language -> German

My aim is

TOKEN LANGUAGE -> English
TOKEN LANGUAGE -> GERMAN

Is there another instead of using any foreign language what I will never use as a PSEUDO_LANGUAGE?

Answer (score 1):

With the command:

xcodebuild -exportLocalizations -localizationPath . -project "YourProject.xcodeproj" -exportLanguage en

you can set the target language and then its working.
I thank myself :-)